# Making a safe entry with a searchable multiple list Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-365

I am making an entry data for that I implemented an internet code to make a comboBox with the capacity to search inside a range of cells. The code works well if in the data validating list the value of the reference is an absolute range (per ex. `='Posibles valores'!$P$4:$P$103`). But I would like to not update the reference and instead just create news rows on a table. I have tried these ways:

1. Create a named range that has a function `=INDIRECT("Tubos_Tipo[Tubos-Tipos]"` in it. Making a reference to a table. But in this case the comboBox just shows the table reference. This way worked to me on data validation list but not without using this macro.
2. On the other hand trying to use a function another function `=OFFSET('Posibles valores'!$P$4;0;0;COUNTA('Posibles valores'!$P$4:'Posibles valores'!$P$1000);1))` but It gives an error `you cannot use reference operators (such as unions, intersections, and intervals), array constants, or the LAMBDA function for Validation of specific data`.

This is the code of the searcheable comboBox with some comments:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim xCombox As OLEObject
Dim xStr As String
Dim xWs As Worksheet
Dim xArr
 
Set xWs = Application.ActiveSheet
On Error Resume Next
Set xCombox = xWs.OLEObjects("TempCombo")
With xCombox
    .ListFillRange = ""
    .LinkedCell = ""
    .Visible = False
End With
If Target.Validation.Type = 3 Then
    Target.Validation.InCellDropdown = False
    Cancel = True
    xStr = Target.Validation.Formula1
    xStr = Right(xStr, Len(xStr) - 1)
    Set nameRangeFormula = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Names(xStr)
    nameRangeFormula = Right(nameRangeFormula, Len(nameRangeFormula) - 1)
    Dim rangeFormula As Range
    'Application.ActiveSheet.Select
    'Set rangeFormula = Range(nameRangeFormula).Select
    
    Set rangeFormula = Names(nameRangeFormula).RefersToRange
    If xStr = "" Then Exit Sub
    With xCombox
        .Visible = True
        .Left = Target.Left
        .Top = Target.Top
        .Width = Target.Width + 5
        .Height = Target.Height + 5
        '.ListFillRange = rangeFormula
        .ListFillRange = xStr
        If .ListFillRange = "" Then
            xArr = Split(xStr, ",")
            Me.TempCombo.List = xArr
        End If
        .LinkedCell = Target.Address
    End With
    xCombox.Activate
    Me.TempCombo.DropDown
End If
```

```
Private Sub TempCombo_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    Select Case KeyCode
        Case 9
            Application.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
        Case 13
            Application.ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    End Select
End Sub
```

I don't know much from VBA more than what I have learnt this past two weeks. Firstly I would like to know if there is some way to execute a function and return the Range. In the case that it is not possible the only way in my mind to resolve thisto create a method with the table header referece as parameter create a Range.

The last two things, the macro functionality of searchable is used on each column with list validation that the code is in it. Is there any way to select exclusive the worksheet and columns they can be used. This code allows to give a wrong result. It just highlights with a green corner the wrong fields, any way to remove if It's wrong or make a pop up windows like the default data validation.

Thanks in advance

Edit: I achived to activate the comboBox for just the columns I wanted with this `If Target.Column = 3 Or Target.Column = 4 Then` before doing the first big `if`. For what I'm understanding each "page" has it's own code. Is this correct?